# ¿Cómo podría usar en jsp una variable en un <li>?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Estoy realizando una tarea en la cual a partir de unos datos tengo que generar en web una ventana emergente con unos datos tipo listado.

Los datos se obtienen de una tabla en sql Server mediante unas consultas en java y luego creo una vista a la que le envío los datos necesarios a una jsp mediante un model and view. Los datos llegan perfectamente a la jsp.
Mi problema aparece cuando con esos datos o parámetros quiero crear una variable con un texto e insertarla dentro de una etiqueta li> de una lista desordenada 
La variable con el texto está bien formada,lo comprobé con un alert.
El código de la jsp sería el siguiente

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%> 
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/comun/directivas.jsp"%>

<div id="confConfirmacionCierrePresupuesto" style="display: none">
<!-- Tamaños: tipo=10,departamento=14,Estado=13,NumEntidadSeccion al ser la última columna no influye                   -->
<!-- Los líneas posteriores tienen que poseer ese formato -->
    <ul>
        <li class="cabeceraListadoCierrePresupuesto">
            <****:mensaje code="etiqueta.cabeceraTipo"/>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
           <****:mensaje code="etiqueta.cabeceraDepartamento" />
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <****:mensaje code="etiqueta.cabeceraEstado" />
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
            <****:mensaje code="etiqueta.cabeceraNumEntidadSeccion" />
        </li>

        <li><br/>${enviablesDepartamentoXestion} Aquí metería el valor de la variable directamente</li> 
        <c:if test = "${enviablesTotalGastos > 0}">
         <li>${enviablesTotalIngresos}</li>
        </c:if>
    </ul>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

//creo las variables con los contadores calculados en el controller
var enviablesTotalGastos="${enviablesTotalGastos}";
var enviablesTotalIngresos="${enviablesTotalIngresos}";
var enviablesDepartamentoPresupuestos="${enviablesDepartamentoPresupuestos}";
var enviableGastosSinValidar="${enviableGastosSinValidar}";
var enviableGastosValidado="${enviableGastosValidado}";
var enviablesTotalGastos="${enviablesTotalGastos}";
var enviableGastosConErrores="${enviableGastosConErrores}";

//creo las variables que se visualizarán 
var tipoingresos = "Ingresos";
var tipogastos = "Gastos";
var estadoValidado = "Validado";
//variables que cambian según sea gallego o castellano
    if (global_locale ==='gl'){
        var departamentoPresupuestos =" Orzamentos";
        var departamentoGestion = "Xestión";
        var estadoSinValidar = "Sen validar";
        var estadoConErrores = "Con erros";
    }
    else{
        var departamentoPresupuestos =" Presupuestos";
        var departamentoGestion = "Gestión";
        var estadoSinValidar = "Sin validar";
        var estadoConErrores = "Con errores";
    }

// ejemplo de concatenacion
var cadena1="hola";
var cadena2="Mundo";
var cadena3="      ";
var cadena4= cadena1+cadena3+cadena2;
alert (cadena4);
</script>
```

Comentar que quité las llaves de apertura de las etiquetas porque si no el editor de texto de la página lo tomaba por lo que no era.

El código claramente no está finalizado.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si añades cualquier código fuente en una pregunta o respuesta, lo seleccionas todo y pulsas Ctrl+K, se formateará

Comment: Para la siguiente lo haré. Gracias

Comment: yo te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y pongas el codigo correctamente formateado, se hace dificil la lectura si no lo esta.

Comment: Formateo realizado para una lectura más fácil. Gracias

Comment: Lo que no visualizas son `${enviablesDepartamentoXestion}` y `${enviablesTotalIngresos}` ? de que manera pruebas que efectivamente estan disponibles esos valores en el jsp?

Comment: Klaimmore .La verdad es que eso lo visualizo sin problema. Al ser variables pasadas en el model and view desde el controlador puedo usarlas dentro de las etiquetas <li> llamándolas de esa manera . El problema está, por ejemplo,  si quiero usar la variable enviablesDepartamentoXestion que no me se como hacer que se muestre. Ya sé que si pongo ${enviablesDepartamentoXestion} puedo ver lo mismo pero, me gustaría aprender a como hacer para ver variables en el documento html.